# Arithmetic Error in Calculation of the Limit of a Given Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I consider a function $f(x)$ which is equal to $\dfrac{\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-6}$

While trying to evaluate the $\lim_{x \to 6} f(x)$

It is true that $\dfrac{\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-6} = \dfrac{\frac{3}{x}}{x-6}-\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{x-6}$

It is also true that $\dfrac{a}{\frac{b}{c}} = \dfrac{a\cdot c}{b}$

I apply this property to $f(x)$ and come to the conclusion that $\dfrac{\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-6} = \dfrac{\frac{3}{x}}{x-6}-\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{x-6} = \dfrac{3x-18}{x}-\dfrac{x-6}{2}$, which is of course incorrect.

Additionally, I believe I'm taking an improper approach to solving this limit.

Comment: $\frac{\frac12}{x-6} \neq \frac{x-6}{2}$ - that's the only error

Comment: @VolodymyrFomenko Sure--but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: $$\frac a{\frac bc} = \frac{ac}b$$

You arrive at only $ac$.

Also, $$\dfrac{\frac ab}{c} = \frac{a}{bc}$$

So $$ \dfrac{\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-6} = \dfrac{\frac{3}{x}}{x-6}-\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{x-6} = \frac{3}{x(x-6)} - \frac 1{2(x-6)} = \frac{2\cdot 3}{2x(x-6)}-\frac{x}{2x(x-6)} = \dfrac{6-x}{2x(x-6)}$$

$$= \frac{-(x-6)}{2x(x-6)} = \frac{-1}{2x}$$

Comment: Right. I fixed that. I was applying that in practice, but I wrote it down wrong. That statement is true and correct, no? Why then am I arriving at an incorrect equality?

Comment: I don't quite understand why that is. What am I missing here? Isn't $\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c} = a \div b \div c = \dfrac{a}{\dfrac{b}{c}}$

Comment: No: Multiply by $1 = \frac bb$ $$\dfrac{\frac ab}{c}\cdot \frac bb = \frac a{bc}$$

Comment: I'm really not certain why this is so incredibly outlandish and difficult for me to grasp. Perhaps I have a weak intuition of the the property in the first place. It is true that $(a \cdot b^{-1})c^{-1} = \dfrac{a}{b \cdot c}$, and $a \cdot (b \cdot c^{-1})^{-1} = \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{c}}{b}$ but $a \cdot b^{-1})^{-1} \neq a \cdot (b \cdot c^{-1})^{-1}$

Comment: $$(ab^{-1})^{-1} = \left(\frac ab\right)^{-1} = \frac{a^{-1}}{b^{-1}}= \frac ba$$

Comment: I made a typo. Retyping.

Comment: $$a(bc^{-1})^{-1} = a{b^{-1}}c = \frac ab \cdot c = \frac {ac}{b}$$

Comment: Ok, it turns out I have no idea what I was talking about. So, even I'm at a loss. I think I just forgot how to do division for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

it is equivalent to $\frac{\frac{6-x}{2x}}{x-6}=-\frac{x-6}{2x(x-6}$
since $\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{6}{2x}-\frac{x}{2x}$

Comment: ... care to elaborate on why?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac 3 x\cdot 2x = 6\text{ since $x$ cancels, and }\frac 1 2\cdot 2x = x\text{ since $2$ cancels.}
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-6}=\frac{\left(\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)2x}{(x-6)2x} = \frac{6-x}{(x-6)2x} = \frac{-1(x-6)}{(x-6)2x} = \frac{-1}{2x}
$$